# result iteration inside OrientDB Javascript server side function

Tags: javascript, function, server-side, orientdb

Inside a javascript function, I have a few queries such as:

```
sQuery = "select in('E_Edge').@rid as id from ?";
result = db.command ('sql', sQuery,[givenId]);
```

If I return the result, it can look like this:

```
[  
   {  
  "@type":"d",
  "@rid":"#-2:0",
  "@version":0,
  "id":[  
     "#35:62",
     "#35:63",
     "#35:64",
     "#35:65",
     "#35:69"
  ],
  "@fieldTypes":"id=z"
   }
]
```

If I want to get the list of ids, I can do:

```
var ids= result[0].getProperty("id");
```

If I return it, I get the expanded ids, i.e. the list of nodes with those ids.

However, If I want to iterate over it and do other operations, `ids.length` doesn't exist as a property, size() is not available.

**How can I iterate through the list?**

Answer (score 3):

If you want iterate the list (if I understand correctly) for doing other operations you can try this:

```
var db=orient.getGraph();
var result=db.command('sql',"select in('E_Edge').@rid as id from Test where @rid='"+rid+"'");

for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{
  var ids=result[i].getProperty("id");
  print(ids);
}
```

If it's not what are you looking for can you explain it better?

Let me know.

Comment: hi, that's not working, as result.length is 1. The list of ids I want to iterate over, are inside the result array, which contains 1 object, which contains a property, "id", which is an array. And this final array is what I want to iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your case with this structure:

```
create class Person extends V
create class Movie extends V
create class acts_In extends E
create class directed extends E
create class friend extends E
create class rated extends E

create property Person.name String
create property Person.surname String
create property Movie.title String

create vertex Person set name="Tom", surname="Hanks"
create vertex Person set name="Robin", surname="Wright"
create vertex Person set name="Helen", surname="Hunt"
create vertex Person set name="Robert", surname="Zemeckis"
create vertex Person set name="Russell", surname="Crowe"
create vertex Person set name="Ben", surname="Affleck"
create vertex Person set name="Kevin", surname="Macdonald"
create vertex Person set name="John"
create vertex Person set name="Mark"
create vertex Person set name="Paul"
create vertex Person set name="Mel", surname="Gibson"
create vertex Person set name="Nancy", surname="Meyers"
create vertex Movie set title="Forrest Gump"
create vertex Movie set title="Cast Away"
create vertex Movie set title="State of Play"
create vertex Movie set title="What Women Want"

create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Tom" and surname="Hanks") to (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Tom" and surname="Hanks") to (select from Movie where title="Cast Away")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Robin" and surname="Wright") to (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Robin" and surname="Wright") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt") to (select from Movie where title="Cast Away")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt") to (select from Movie where title="What Women Want")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Mel" and surname="Gibson") to (select from Movie where title="What Women Want")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Russell" and surname="Crowe") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Ben" and surname="Affleck") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge friend from (select from Person where name="Mel" and surname="Gibson") to (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt")
create edge friend from (select from Person where name="Ben" and surname="Affleck") to (select from Person where name="Russell" and surname="Crowe")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="What Women Want") to (select from Person where name="Nancy" and surname="Meyers")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="Cast Away") to (select from Person where name="Robert" and surname="Zemeckis")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump") to (select from Person where name="Robert" and surname="Zemeckis")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="State of Play") to (select from Person where name="Kevin" and surname="Macdonald")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="What Women Want") to (select from Person where name="Paul")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="Cast Away") to (select from Person where name="John")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump") to (select from Person where name="Mark")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="State of Play") to (select from Person where name="John")
```

**QUERY**: Select the actors who acted in the `Movie` with `@rid 13:2` ('State of Play')

Now you can try different approaches to retrieve the results you're looking for:

1. Using a simple `SELECT FROM @rid` query:

   **CODE**:

   ```
   var db = orient.getGraph();
   var givenId = '13:2';
   var actorsList=[];
   var sQuery = "select from ?";
   var result = db.command('sql',sQuery, [givenId]);
   for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
     var in_acts_In = result[i].getRecord().field('in_acts_In.out');
     if(in_acts_In!=null){
       var actorsIter=in_acts_In.iterator();
       if(actorsIter!=null){
         while(actorsIter.hasNext()){
           var iteratedActor=actorsIter.next();
           actorsList.push(iteratedActor.getRecord());
         }
       }
     }
   }
   return actorsList;
   ```

   **OUTPUT**:

   ```
   [
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:1",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Robin",
           "surname": "Wright",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:2",
               "#14:3"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g"
       },
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:4",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Russell",
           "surname": "Crowe",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:7"
           ],
           "in_friend": [
               "#16:1"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g,in_friend=g"
       },
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:5",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Ben",
           "surname": "Affleck",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:8"
           ],
           "out_friend": [
               "#16:1"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g,out_friend=g"
       }
   ]
   ```
2. `expand()` the results of your query:

   **CODE**:

   ```
   var db=orient.getGraph();
   var givenId = '13:2';
   var actorsList=[];
   var result=db.command('sql',"select expand(in('acts_In')) from ?",[givenId]);
   for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
   {
     var actor=result[i].getRecord();
     actorsList.push(actor);;
   }
   return actorsList;
   ```

   **OUTPUT**:

   ```
   [
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:1",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Robin",
           "surname": "Wright",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:2",
               "#14:3"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g"
       },
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:4",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Russell",
           "surname": "Crowe",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:7"
           ],
           "in_friend": [
               "#16:1"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g,in_friend=g"
       },
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:5",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Ben",
           "surname": "Affleck",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:8"
           ],
           "out_friend": [
               "#16:1"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g,out_friend=g"
       }
   ]
   ```
3. Using an input function parameter (`rid` with value `13:2` in my case):

   **CODE**:

   ```
   var db=orient.getGraph();
   var result=db.command('sql',"select in('acts_In').@rid as id from "+rid);
   for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
   {
     var idList=result[i].getProperty("id");
   }
   return idList;
   ```

   **OUTPUT**:

   ```
   [
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:1",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Robin",
           "surname": "Wright",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:2",
               "#14:3"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g"
       },
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:4",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Russell",
           "surname": "Crowe",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:7"
           ],
           "in_friend": [
               "#16:1"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g,in_friend=g"
       },
       {
           "@type": "d",
           "@rid": "#12:5",
           "@version": 3,
           "@class": "Person",
           "name": "Ben",
           "surname": "Affleck",
           "out_acts_In": [
               "#14:8"
           ],
           "out_friend": [
               "#16:1"
           ],
           "@fieldTypes": "out_acts_In=g,out_friend=g"
       }
   ]
   ```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Mihai, did you have a chance to try the function ?